# UIPanGestureRecognizer won't pan right

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIView subclass to which I have added a UIPanGestureRocognizer:

```
_panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
_panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
_panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self addGestureRecognizer:_panGestureRecognizer];
```

This view is used in a view hierarchy which includes a UISplitViewController as the top-level view/controller.

When testing this in the iPad simulator in landscape orientation, if I start the pan by going up/down/left, my `handlePanGesture:` method is called as expected. However, if I start the pan by going *right* then my `handlePanGesture:` method is *not* called. Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I was writing up this question, I figured out the answer for myself:

The UISplitViewController since iOS 5 will, by default, recognize a swipe gesture to the right and display the popover controller. This is obvious in portrait orientation, however, in landscape orientation, the gesture has no apparent effect because the left-side view displayed as the popover in portrait is always displayed in landscape.

The solution to this is to disable the swipe gesture for the UISplitViewController with:

```
splitViewController.presentsWithGesture = NO;
```

I don't know if there is a way to have both gestures work.

Comment: You could also mess around with `recognizerSimultaneousGesture:` if you needed to retain the swipe gesture functionality.

Comment: If you're referring to `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` in `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, I tried implementing that and just returning `YES` for all inputs, but it had no effect.

Comment: You could also need to add some logic to determine whether or not to return YES. but yea thats what I was referring to just incase you weren't aware.